# Inline for recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, inline

The inline function is replaced by its code in the phase when the gcc generate the asm code.

What will be the behaviour  when using inline for recursive function

```
inline int fact (int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * fact(n-1));
}
```

I generate the asm code with `gcc -S` when the recursive function is with `inline` prefix and when the recursive function is without the `inline` prefix and I found that the asm code for both cases is the same.

Have You any explanation for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `inline` is just an suggestion to the compiler which compiler may or may not accept. It is not binding on the compiler to adhere to your suggestion. An intelligent compiler will inline a function if it can even without the suggestion. Usually, for recursive functions compilers will do till certain depths.

> **Why the compiler does not `inline` your function?**

With recursive functions compilers will usually look for the opportunity to perform ***[tail call optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailCallOptimization)***. Your function is **not tail call recursive**.

Comment: Does the `inline` prefix force the compiler to use tail call optimization (when it's allowed) even if the compiler is not smart (to detect automatically such behaviour)

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: `inline` prefix does not force the compiler to do any optimization.While It has little effect in making the compiler substitute function definition inline to where the call was made the popular notion of `inline` being a mere suggestion is not true as well. It certainly forces one thing. It forces the compiler to relax certain rules w.r.t One definition rule allowing the function to be defined in the header file.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: `inline` doesn't actually tell the compiler that it must inline the function.  Its only required effect is to tell the *linker* that the function may be defined in more than one object file.  (Without `inline`, that would be a link-time error.)

This allows you to have the function definition present in multiple translation units so that the compiler *has the option* to inline the function, without generating a linker error.  Modern compilers may or *may not* consider the presence of the `inline` keyword when deciding whether or not to inline a function.

Comment: @manu-fatto That depends on whether or not this function definition is present in more than one translation unit.  If it is, then without `inline` one would receive an error from the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Every inline function must anyway be compiled in case someone needs a pointer to the function. To check the difference you should use the function somewhere like that:

```
inline int fact (int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * fact(n-1));
}


void main () {
    printf("%d\n", fact(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already said, `inline` is merely a hint, not a directive. The compiler has the final word regarding inlining functions. If you want to force something to be inlined, you can do it with macros. But you can't have recursive macros, as far as I think, so that's a dead end.

That being said, even if you *could* force inlining of functions, you should know that (in any optimization level) compilers can unroll some recursive functions to plain while loops, so you wouldn't see any paradox in the final assembly: the resulting loop would simply be inlined.